# How can I update state in editor react-draft-wysiwyg

Tags: reactjs

Here is how I implement Editor tag

```
const Editor = dynamic(
  () => import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then((mod) => mod.Editor),
  { ssr: false }
);
```

Here is my onChange event:

```
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    // Update state
    updatePlayersData((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
```

Here is my editor tag for update state:

```
<Editor
    wrapperClassName={"mission-editor-wapper"}
    toolbarClassName={"mission-editor-toolbar"}
    editorClassName={"mission-editor-editor"}
    onChange={handleChange}
    name="mission"
    toolbar={{
      options: ["inline", "list", "link"],
      inline: {
        inDropdown: false,
        options: ["bold", "italic", "strikethrough", "underline"],
        bold: {
          icon: "/editor-bold.png",
        },
        italic: {
          icon: "/editor-italic.png",
        },
        strikethrough: {
          icon: "/editor-strike.png",
        },
        underline: {
          icon: "/editor-underline.png",
        },
      },
      list: {
        inDropdown: false,
        className: undefined,
        component: undefined,
        dropdownClassName: undefined,
        options: ["unordered", "ordered"],
        unordered: {
          icon: "/editor-list-bullet.png",
        },
        ordered: {
          icon: "/editor-list-number.png",
        },
      },
      link: {
        inDropdown: false,
        options: ["link"],
        defaultTargetOption: "_blank",
        popupClassName: "editor-link-popup",
        link: {
          icon: "/editor-link.png",
        },
  },
  image: {
    uploadCallback: () => {},
  },
  history: { inDropdown: false },
}}
 />
```

But when I added onChange into my Editor it's giving me error with name is undefined. How can I chang my onChange function? What I need to do?

Thank you so much for helping me

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try basic Debugging? Like, using `console.dir` to see the returned values.

Also, you may require `event.persist()` before actually accessing `event.target` depending upon your React version.

Comment: Yea but I am having a problem right now that I can't update state to my server

Comment: Can you please create a CodeSandbox for the same and link it in the Description?

Comment: Yes I'm doing it right now